# Progmatically generating and applying an OpenGL texture to a OpenGL View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, core-graphics

Ok so i have been trying to work through this, i have managed to Subclass on OpenGLView and get some shapes (squares, triangles) to draw, and get them to change there colour e.t.c

Now i am trying to work out how to load the texture data and render that, but i'm a little lost.

Here is the code i am trying to use, and it doesn't seem to load any kind of texture, i just end up with a white box. It should i believe create a black and white checker box effect, but i can't seem to make it work.

Here's the code, help greatly appreciated!

```
#import "MyOpenGLView.h"
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>

@implementation MyOpenGLView

static void drawAnObject ()


{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLuint tex;

    glGenTextures(1, &tex);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, tex);


    // Black/white checkerboard
    float pixels[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    float color[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, color);

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 0.1, 0.1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);


    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (10.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glEnd ();



}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    renderTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.001   //a 1ms time interval
                                      target:self
                                    selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:renderTimer
                             forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:renderTimer
                             forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode]; //Ensure timer fires during resize
}

// Timer callback method
- (void)timerFired:(id)sender
{

     [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawAnObject();
    glFlush();
    GLint swapInterval = 1;
    [[self openGLContext] setValues:&swapInterval forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];


    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&displayLink);
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

I am looking to develop a Cocoa application for OS X where I have a rectangle, roughly 500px x 500px where i need to change the color of each pixel at around 25fps.

The color value for each pixel will be stored in an NSDictionary which can be read from as each pixel is rendered.

In it's most basic sense, i can subclass the View i am drawing in and override the drawRect method. But, i will then need to call it 25 time a second, and i suspect that's too much to ask and it's going to bog down, it also doesn't guarantee that the render will happen at the correct time.

Soi'm thinking i need to do this at a lower level using Core Graphics or OpenGL, but those are massive subjects that i haven't spent much time with before. So before i dive into one or the other, any pointers on the correct direction?

Comment: Create an OpenGL texture and write the data in every frame with `glTexSubImage2D` https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml. I don't see an easier solution, if your data is only available on the CPU.

Comment: Yeah i feared it would have to be something like that, ok well into the world of OpenGL i go, wish me luck . . .

Comment: Ok, already pretty confused. From what i can tell i need to load the RGB data into and array and feed that into the texture rendered, but i have no overview of the general building blocks to put everything together. What libraries i need to import, how i create the OpenGL view that i am rendering the texture on and how i tell it to update. Any pointers to some tutorials to get me going would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

> ```
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 0.1, 0.1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
> ```

is not doing what you might think it does. The `width` and `height` parameters are of type `GLsizei`, which is an *integer* type - you are supposed to set the *pixel dimensions* of your texture here. You set it to `0.1`, which will be implicitely casted to integer and end up as 0. You shoud use 2 and 2 for a 2-by-2 texture here, obviously.

The call `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, tex);` now makes no sense at all, since `tex` is just some number (more or less) randomly assigned by the GL implementation, and nothing you want the unpack alignment be set to. Since you use `float` as basic data types (which you probably shouldn't, from an performance point of view - but that is another story), the default alignment of 4 bytes will work fine.

Even if you fix that, the texture will not be displayed because it is not _mipmap complete. The default minification filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. If you don't intent to use mipmapping, you must set the filter mode accordingly:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); // or GL_LINEAR
```

The third issue I see is that you *create a new texture object* every time you call `drawAnObject()`, which you never delete - this will leak meomory over time.

You should think about when you want a texture to be created and what life cycle it should have. Changing the image data is possible without recreating the object.

**UPDATE** to answer UPTATE2 in the question:

You are using `glTexSubImage2D` wrong, the parameters are:

`target`, `level`, `xoffset`, `yoffset`, `width`, `height`.

You basically skipped the `level` and inserted another `0` at the position for `height`, so you are trying to update a 4 by 0 sub-area. The correct call would of course be

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, cpixelArray);
```

Comment: Hi Derhass, thanks so much for your help, it's all starting to make sense now, i have it rendering the checkerboard as i wanted and also alternating between two different patterns. However i am indeed leaking memory as you suggested, to combat that i am trying to just update the existing texture, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @GarethJeanne: Well, for some reason, my clairvoyance skills just vanished... ;)

Comment: Sorry, i was trying to post a follow up saying i updated the post but it locked me out for a minute. So, update cost posted above. Thanks!

Comment: Still not working i'm afraid, glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, cpixelArray); works, glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, cpixelArray); doesn't in the same method :(

Comment: I have updated the question to show (most) of the full code i am using. Wondering if i am loosing the pointer to the texture object somehow?

Comment: I have moved the follow up question to another one so i can mark this one as answered. If you where able to take a look at the new question and offer some guidance that would be much appreciated.